# Como leer argumentos y mandar como una lista a una funcion

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo este código que funciona poniendo yo los argumentos, pero yo quiero introducir los argumentos a través del terminal al objeto, haber si me podéis ayudar soy nuevo en esto.

```py
class Operaciones_Enteros:

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

    def Suma(operador):
        resultado = 0
        for valor in operador.args:
            resultado += valor
        return resultado

operacion1 = Operaciones_Enteros()

print(operacion1.Suma())
```

Comment: debes utlizar `import sys` y la luego ` sys.argv` que vendria a ser una lista por ejemplo para el nombre del archivo `sys.argv[0]` para el primer argumento `sys.argv[1]`

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto código pide una lista de valores enteros uno por uno. Para terminar, sólo debes dar ENTER:

```
print("Introduzca los valores uno por uno. Para terminar, ENTER")
lista = []
while True:
    entrada = input("?")
    if entrada:
        lista.append(int(entrada))
    else:
        break
```

La entrada es leida como string. Usamos la función `int()` para convertirla en un entero. Si el problema fuera con decimales, usaría `float()`.

Una vez ingresa la lista, corresponde crear el objeto con

```
operacion1 = Operaciones_Enteros(*lista)
```

Notese el pequeño detalle del asterisco por delante del argumento. Este asterisco hace que la lista se *desempaque* en sus elemento. Si `lista = [1, 2, 3]`, entonces la línea anterior es equivalente a

```
operacion1 = Operaciones_Enteros(1, 2, 3)
```

En `__init__()` usas `*args`, lo que significa *junte todos los argumentos de la llamada real y pongalos en una lista llamada args*. Entonces, si le paso la lista sin más, la va a poner dentro de la lista `args`, quedando así:

```
args = [[1, 2, 3]]
```

cuando lo que quiero es

```
args = [1, 2, 3]
```

#### Demo

Nota: código sin validaciones

```
class Operaciones_Enteros:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

    def suma(self):
        resultado = 0
        for valor in self.args:
            resultado += valor
        return resultado

print("Introduzca los valores uno por uno. Para terminar, ENTER")
lista = []
while True:
    entrada = input("?")
    if entrada:
        lista.append(int(entrada))
    else:
        break
operacion1 = Operaciones_Enteros(*lista)
print(operacion1.suma())
```

produce:

```
Introduzca los valores uno por uno. Para terminar, ENTER
?1
?2
?3
?
6

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Edición: Pasar lista como lista**

Si quieres pasar directamente la lista en llamada (sin el asterisco):

```
operacion1 = Operaciones_Enteros(lista)
```

tendrías que cambiar el `__init__()`, eliminando el asterisco

```
def __init__(self, args):
    self.args = args
```

Ahora la clase recibe un sólo argumento que debe ser una lista de valores. Antes recibía una cantidad variable de valores enteros.

Comment: Excelente buen aporte